# cordova run android - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: cordova, typeerror

`cordova run android` is displaying white screen with following error in chrome inspect of webview

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    
    at inherits (inherits_browser.js:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (parser_stream.js:27)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9ec8f0a9e2870d9ff7e5:587)
    at fn (bootstrap 9ec8f0a9e2870d9ff7e5:111)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:41)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9ec8f0a9e2870d9ff7e5:587)
    at fn (bootstrap 9ec8f0a9e2870d9ff7e5:111)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9ec8f0a9e2870d9ff7e5:587)
    at fn (bootstrap 9ec8f0a9e2870d9ff7e5:111)
```

Current System Properties

```
$ node -v
v8.12.0

$ cordova -v
7.1.0

$ monaca -v
2.7.4

$ npm -v
6.4.1

$ gradle -v
Gradle 4.1
```

[Screenshot where the code break on undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eolm6.png)

Comment: Is it a blank cordova project or you've modified it? Did it broke after any particular modification?

Comment: It is not a blank project. I have modified an existing project and then when I try to build and run the changes, I am unable to view the startup page. It gives me this white page with subject error.

Comment: The error is too generic, we won't be able to tell what causes the error, unless we see the code and understand what changes you made. Put a breakpoint there and see what code is calling this method. Obviously `inherits` is called with `undefined` in the second argument. Try comparing your changes with initial project, try rolling back your changes and steadily reapplying changes.

Answer (score -1):

from what i see on the screenshot the problem is probably on "superCtor.prototype" debug youre code and check the value on superCtor at this point. if its undefined then go back  to the point where superCtor is initialised and make sure it gets a valid value there.